# JSF valueChangeListener not fired on form submission

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

On selecting a DIV element, i take the value of the selected DIV's hidden element and pass it on to a form with hidden element in it. This form is then submitted.
Below are pieces of my code.

The value of the ***hidden input*** inside the form is correctly set 
on selecting the DIV and the ***form is also submitted*** but the valueChangeListener is not fired.

Every hint is welcome!

-choesang

**Form with hidden element:**

```
<a4j:form id="currentForumPost" ajaxSubmit="true" 
          onsubmit="console.log('currentForumPost is submitted'); 
          console.log(jQuery('#currentForumPost:currentPostId').val())" >
       <h:inputHidden id="currentPostId" 
       valueChangeListener="#{forumController.changeListenerSelectedForumPost}" 
       immediate="true"/>
</a4j:form>
```

**DIV element:**

```
<div class="block ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset"  
  onclick="var x = jQuery(this).find('.hiddenInputText').val();        
  jQuery(this).closest('#RightPane').find('#currentForumPost:currentPostId').val(x);      
  jQuery(this).closest('#RightPane').find('#currentForumPost').submit();">
  <h:inputText value="#{post.uuid}" styleClass="hiddenInputText"/>
                      ......
</div>
```

**Java**

```
public void changeListenerSelectedForumPost(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
setSelectedForumPost(event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("value").toString());
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you do not have a `valueChangeListener` attribute on the inputText. You need this attribute so JSF knows which listener to call. Assuming your bean is named 'bean', here is an example:

```
<h:inputText value="#{post.uuid}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeListenerSelectedForumPost}" styleClass="hiddenInputText" />
```

Comment: Hi Colin, 
Thanks for answering my post. Part of my code was not visible, sorry about that. I do have a valueChangeListener, not exactly for the element <h:inputText> but for <h:inputHidden>. 

Please note that, <h:inputHidden> is the element submitted to the server side.

Comment: Ok. Nothing looks obviously wrong now. Does it work if you change the h:inputHidden to an h:inputText?